# Bedeutung von "soziale Einbettung"

Tags: meaning

> Mit dem Begriff "alleinerziehend" werde fälschlicherweise oft **mangelnde soziale Einbettung** oder Erziehungsqualität assoziiert.

Was bedeutet der Ausdruck "soziale Einbettung"?

Comment: Was würdest Du vermuten?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Das Konzept der sozialen Einbettung zählt mittlerweile zum festen Bestandteil der Soziologie.

Soziale Einbindung (Einbettung) ist das Ausmaß, mit dem Menschen in Kontakt zu anderen Personen stehen, entweder zu privaten Freunden oder zu Kollegen am Arbeitsplatz.

Diese Einbindung (Einbettung) wird von einem selbst stärker wahrgenommen, wenn man zur jeweiligen Gruppe gut passt.

Eine gute soziale Einbindung schütz vor Stress, weil man andere um Hilfe bitten kann und etwa so seine Arbeit so schneller erledigen kann.

Mehr (notwendige) Kontakte mit vielen Personen kann aber auch mehr sozialen Stress bedeuten.